# Is there a "just my code" feature in NetBeans C++?

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans

I'm debugging a C++ 11 project in NetBeans 7.4 under Debian, and I'm having a problem with this code:

```
shared_ptr<my_obj> node;
node->func();
```

When debugging the second line, the debugger steps inside the shared_ptr code ('->' operator overload code).

Is there a way to tell the debugger to debug only the project code? Like 'Just My Code' in VS?

I'm not talking about a step-over vs step-into problem. When I try to step into, I'd like the debugger to step into *my own code*, meaning the code in func(). Instead, it steps into the shared_ptr `->` operator overload code.

With the 'Just My Code' feature, and debugger skips the c++ code, and goes straight into the 'interesting' code

Comment: Use `next` instead of `step`.

Comment: Can't find `next`. Where is it? I do want it to step into the func(), just not to the shared_ptr code

Comment: Use F8 to use `next` command, that's what you want. If you want to go inside a function or method, press F7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably netbeans is using a GUI front-end to the native linux debugger, `gdb`.  The issue you are referring to is the difference between the `next` and `step` commands.

Looking at [this simple tutorial](http://cobweb.cs.uga.edu/~shoulami/sp2009/cs1301/tutorial/NetBeansDebuggerTutorial/NetBeansDebuggerTutorial.htm), it seems that the netbeans interface refers to these as *"Step Over"* (button with curved arrow) and *"Step Into"* (button with straight downward arrow) respectively; you want to use the former instead of the latter.  The button with the straight upward arrow (*"Step Out"*) is the equivalent of gdb's `finish`.

More specifically, it sounds like you want to **step over** the first line declaring the shared_ptr and **step into** the next line.  If you find yourself having accidentally stepped into something you aren't interested in (or you're done somewhere you were), **step out** should take you back to the line that called the function you stepped into by completing the call.

If the issue is that the debugger enters the `->` operator code for shared_ptr when you step in, you should be able to get through this with **step out**.  The GUI will probably then show you as still being on the same `node->func()` line (the `->` call has completed returning a pointer to the shared object).  If you now press **step in** again, you should be on the first line of `my_obj::func`.

Comment: Step over, or `next` doesn't go into the function. What I need it to do is to skip the code belonging to the c++ language, and go straight into my own code, in func()

Comment: I've added a paragraph about that.  You want to step over one and step into the next one.  Each action only proceeds once, so this is possible.  Click *step over*, then when the `->func()` line is highlighted, click *step into*.

Comment: I've edited the question - The problem occurs when debugging the second line.

Comment: Okay, I follow.  Using `gdb` directly, you can get through that by using `finish`, which should be the netbeans "Step Out" button.  That won't take you to the next line of your source, though -- you'll still be on the `->func()` line. Now "Step In" *again* and you'll end up in `func()`.  I've added a 4th paragraph about that.

Comment: Okay, so it's *step-in, step-out, and step-in again*. Not exactly what I was looking for - But it works perfectly! Thanks!